# How to use select query from csv file with second row as header (ADODB connection).Need to skip first row

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, csv, adodb

Connection String

```
 Dim Db = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & SourcePath & ";Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;"";"
```

the Header is start from 2nd row, how to exclude 1st row while using Select query from CSV file. Please help to amend the connection string to start from second row
Sample Query.....
Select [Col1], Col1/Col2 as [Average] From [CSV File] Where Col3 > 0

Answer (score 0):

In order to get your rows by a file .csv you can use this method as an alternative which gives you a list of rows that contains an array by columns.
Replace the separator char with the separator that is used in your file CSV also the path of your CSV file

```
    Dim separator As Char = CChar(";")
    Dim linesWithoutHeader As List(Of String()) = (From line In IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\yourPathCsvFile.csv")
                                                   Select row = line.Split(separator)
                                                   Skip 1).ToList
```